# java regex minimum character not working

Tags: java, regex

```
^[a-zA-Z1-9][a-zA-Z1-9_\\.-]{2,64}[^\\.-]$
```

this is the regex that should match the following conditions

should start only with alphabets and numbers ,
contains alphabets numbers ,dot and hyphen
should not end with hyphen

it works for all conditions but when i try with three character like

```
vu6
111
aaa
```

after four characters validation is working properly did i miss anything

Comment: Change `{2,64}` to `{1,64}`.

Comment: but its failing for 2 charcters aa

Comment: Then `^[a-zA-Z1-9](?:[a-zA-Z1-9_.-]{0,64}[a-zA-Z1-9])?$`. Do you really want to avoid matching strings having `0` in them? Note that `[^\\.-]` matches `§` as it matches any char other than `.` and `-`, is it intended?

Comment: shall i know why my regex failed , also since it worked can you post as answer

Comment: Have you searched about it? I'm sure lots of helpful questions exist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Reason** why your Regex doesn't work:

Hope breaking it into smaller pieces will help:

```
^[a-zA-Z1-9][a-zA-Z1-9_\\.-]{2,64}[^\\.-]$
```

`[a-zA-Z1-9]:` Will match a single alphanumeric character ( except for _ )

`[a-zA-Z1-9_\\.-]{2,64}:` Will match alphanumeric character + "." + -

`[^\\.-]:` Will expect exactly 1 character which should not be "." or "-"

**Solution:**

You can use 2 simple regex:

This answer assumes that the length of the string you want to match lies between **[3-65] (both inclusive)**

First, that will actually validate the string

```
[a-zA-Z1-9][a-zA-Z1-9_\\.-]{2,64}
```

Second, that will check the char doesn't end with ".|-"

```
[^\\.-]$
```

**In Java**

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z1-9][a-zA-Z1-9_\\.-]{2,64}$");
            Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("[^\\.-]$");
            Matcher m1 = pattern1.matcher(input);
            Matcher m2 = pattern1.matcher(input);
            if(m1.find() && m2.find()) {
                System.out.println("found");
            }
```

Comment: Note that `[a-zA-Z1-9]` will not match `0`.

Comment: @MikeHarris Yes, Hope that's the part of OP's requirement

Comment: The solution suggested is not as per the requirement: *contains alphabets numbers ,dot and hyphen* because `[^.-]` matches any char but `.` and `-`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew String was a typo in my answer I have updated the answer as well with actual code

Comment: Ok, but it still does not support `a` or `ab`.

Comment: Who wants to support it??  Op doesn't mention anything about it